# Firefox doesn't update (since the plugin issue of may 3rd)

Tags: software-installation

Mozilla apparently screw up big time last week with a certificate which deactivated every plugins I had installed. The newest update from May 5th fix this issue from what I've read on their website but elementary OS doesn't provide the update. Usually Firefox gets updated via the Application Center.

How can Firefox be updated (without reinstalling and customizing everything).

PS: no tags in correlation with my issue are working.. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not receiving update using package manager because Firefox is not yet updated to the latest version in [bionic beaver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/) on which elementary OS Juno is built. As soon as Firefox is updated in the bionic beaver, you will also be able to update it here in elementary OS.

I have a *workaround* not solution sadly. But I think its better to follow this instead of messing with installed source because the package will be updated shortly.

Please download the latest version of Firefox from its official website and extract it a folder. The download file mostl likely come as *tar* compressed file. Please open terminal in the directory where your downloaded file is stored and execute `tar -xvjf firefox-66.0.5.tar.bz2`.

This will extract Firefox in "firefox" named folder. Please execute `cd firefox` to change directory to that folder and execute `./firefox` to launch Firefox. Make sure all instance of old version is closed before you execute last command to fire up new firefox.

New Firefox will load of everything from the installed-old one. Keep using it until its updated in the repository of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip! Fortunately the latest update was available today but I'll remember this in case of a similar issue in the future. :)